# Using Regex to replace multiple lines of text in file

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, scripting

Basically, I have a .bas file that I am looking to update.  Basically the script requires some manual configuration and I don't want my team to need to reconfigure the script every time they run it.  What I would like to do is have a tag like this

```
<BEGINREPLACEMENT>
'MsgBox ("Loaded")


ReDim Preserve STIGArray(i - 1)
ReDim Preserve SVID(i - 1)

STIGArray = RemoveDupes(STIGArray)
SVID = RemoveDupes(SVID)
<ENDREPLACEMENT>
```

I am kind of familiar with powershell so what I was trying to do is to do is create an update file and to replace what is in between the tags with the update.  What I was trying to do is:

```
$temp = Get-Content C:\Temp\file.bas
$update = Get-Content C:\Temp\update
$regex = "<BEGINREPLACEMENT>(.*?)<ENDREPLACEMENT>"

$temp -replace $regex, $update
$temp | Out-File C:\Temp\file.bas
```

The issue is that it isn't replacing the block of text.  I can get it to replace either  or  but I can't get it to pull in everything in between.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to how I can do this?

Comment: You need to use `-Raw`  when reading files in and a `"(?s)<BEGINREPLACEMENT>.*?<ENDREPLACEMENT>"` regex. Also, use escape dollars in dynamic replacement `$temp -replace $regex, $update.Replace('$', '$$')`

Comment: Yupp that was it (Reading it in as -Raw and updating regex)!  Im not sure why the regex needs to be different though doesn't mine look for anything in between the two tags?

Comment: The `.` does not match a newline char by default.

Comment: Got it. Well that completely solved my issue.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you read the whole files in with newlines, which is possible with the `-Raw` option passed to `Get-Content`.

Then, `.` does not match a newline char by default, hence you need to use a `(?s)` inline DOTALL (or "singleline") option.

Also, if your dynamic content contains something like `$2` you may get an exception since this is a backreference to Group 2 that is missing from your pattern. You need to process the replacement string by doubling each `$` in it.

```
$temp = Get-Content C:\Temp\file.bas -Raw
$update = Get-Content C:\Temp\update -Raw
$regex = "(?s)<BEGINREPLACEMENT>.*?<ENDREPLACEMENT>"
$temp -replace $regex, $update.Replace('$', '$$')
```